# Determine integral range in function of 2 random variables.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, improper-integrals

> X and Y are independent uniform r.vs in the common interval (0,1).
>   Determine where Z = X + Y.

There are 2 ranges of z: $0 < z < 1$ and $1<z<2$.

The diagrams given for both ranges to find $F_z(z)$ is given as follows.

[image]

For $1<z<2$,

$$F_z(z) = 1-P(Z>z) = 1-\int_{y=z-1}^{1}\int_{x=z-y}^{1} 1 \,dx \,dy$$

I understand the integral over x, but I don't understand how to get the integral over y, i.e. $\int_{y=z-1}^{1}$. How is the $y=z-1$ obtained?

Comment: If you _must_ use integrals, then look at the answers to the question I referred to in my other comment. But if you simply want to _find_ the probability that $(X,Y)$ lies in the regions marked, then be aware that _in this case_, these probabilities are just the area of the regions under consideration.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I see that convolution was used in the other question to get $f_Y(z-x)$ first. Is there a way to see the range without using convolution, just from the diagrams above?

Comment: For _fixed_ $z, 1 < z < 2$, say $z=1.5$, you are finding the volume under the $f(x,y)$ _surface_ in the triangular region with vertices $(z-1,1)=(0.5,1),(1,1)$, and $(1,z-1)=(1,0.5)$. Fix a $y$ between $z-1=0.5$ and $1$, say $y=0.8$  Then, $x$ varies from $z-y=0.7$ to $1$ giving $\int_{x=0.7}^1f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx$, and then $y$ varies from $z-1=0.5$ to $1$ giving the final answer as $$P\{X+Y > 1.5\} = \int_{y=0.5}^1\int_{x=1.5-y}^1f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks!